# strange Resharper warning on MemberInfo.DeclaringType

Tags: c#, reflection, resharper, resharper-5.1

Resharper tells me that MemberInfo.DeclaringType can never be null:
[image]

However when that code is run, the text "Top level member" is printed. I don't get it, what's wrong here?

Comment: Did you do a full clean and rebuild?  Often resharper puts up odd warnings because it hasn't rerun its analysis recently enough. Otherwise it may just be a bug.

Comment: @CMP, jep I did. And I find it strange that this would be a bug, since the attributes such as NotNullAttribute, are automatically assigned to standard libraries. If there was a bug in that code, that must have been noticed before.

Comment: I meant a bug in resharper's static analysis engine.

Comment: [MemberInfo.DeclaringType's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx) even says it will return null in some cases.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266010/can-propertyinfo-declaringtype-really-ever-be-null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resharper is simply wrong here.  `MemberInfo` is an `abstract` type and it's possible for an arbitrary implementation to return whatever it pleases including `null`

Example:

```
class EvilMemberInfo : MemberInfo
{
    public override System.Type DeclaringType
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    // Rest omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the override System.Type uses for DeclaringType. Maybe they should call it EvilType. =]

Comment: I recently claimed to have found a bug in Resharper, but it turned out I was wrong. This time however, I stated my question a bit less aggressive, but I do agree with you.

Comment: @rsbarro, no! That's not exactly the override for System.Type, since types can be nested....

Comment: @JBSnorro Not following you there. Looking in ILSpy, System.Type is abstract, it overrides the DeclaringType property, and it returns null on the getter. What am I missing?

Comment: @rsbarro, I was thinking of the scenario class Foo{public class Bar{}}, where typeof(Foo.Bar).DeclaringType is not null. But you're correct, sorry :P

Answer (score 10):

Microsoft Code Contracts states that it is never null.

```
// System.Reflection.MemberInfo
public virtual Type DeclaringType
{
    get
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Type>() != null, null, "Contract.Result<Type>() != null");
        Type result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

So ReSharper relies on Code Contracts here.

Comment: Ok, I've posted it on the code contracts forum, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/fdf1436a-e843-408c-b932-c012e03e72cd