# Can PropertyInfo.DeclaringType really ever be null?

Tags: c#, reflection, resharper

I'm using ReSharper (older version), which used to warn me when I use `PropertyInfo.DeclaringType` that it can be `null`.

It doesn't make sense to me at first and second glances. Is it really true, or is ReSharper a bit dumb and doesn't notice that it's a `PropertyInfo`, not a general `MemberInfo`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `PropertyInfo.DeclaringType` property is inherited from `MemberInfo.DeclaringType` and from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype):

> If the `MemberInfo` object is a global member (that is, if it was
>   obtained from the `Module.GetMethods` method, which returns global
>   methods on a module), the returned `DeclaringType` will be `null`.

So, warning seems fine in that case.

Answer (score 11):

It can be `null` if the property is defined in a module. In C# you cannot define such methods and properties without reflection (see `PropertyBuilder`). However, if you reference a VB.NET assembly, it can have such members.